# Cotejamiento de datos en Oracle y PHP

Tags: php, oracle, utf-8

Tengo un CRUD con MVC hecho en PHP y la base de datos es Oracle. Al momento de guardar strings con caracteres con acento, tengo el siguiente problema. Por ejemplo, cuando guardo la palabra "médico" en el formulario, esto me lo guarda como "m??dico" en Oracle.

Probé usar la función utf8_encode de PHP en el modelo, pero no hace nada.

Aquí está todo el código:
https://github.com/ashcrimson/newcyc/blob/master/pages/contratos/contratosNew/model.php

Lo que hice está en la línea 171:

```
if(isset($_POST["objeto_contrato"]) && $_POST["objeto_contrato"] != ""){
            $this->params .= "objeto_contrato" . $_POST["objeto_contrato"] . "&";
            $this->objeto_contrato = utf8_encode($_POST["objeto_contrato"]);
            
        }
```

Para más información, aquí tengo la vista, donde está el formulario
https://github.com/ashcrimson/newcyc/blob/master/pages/contratos/contratosNew/view.php

En la línea 373 estoy pidiendo el campo:

```
<div class="container">
                    <div class="row col-12">
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 <?=$objeto_contrato ? 'has-error' : '' ;?>">
                            <label>Objeto del contrato *</label>
                            
                            <input type="text" name="objeto_contrato" class="form-control"
                                value="<?=$_GET["objeto_contrato"] ?? $registroEdit['OBJETO_CONTRATO'] ?? ''?>"
                            >
                            <?php if ($objeto_contrato){ ?>
                            <span class="help-block text-danger"> 
                                <strong>Error: Numero de licitacion vacio</strong>
                            </span>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Hasta el momento me sigue guardando los acentos como "??". ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Y qué locale le configuraste a la instancia de Oracle, ¿we8mswin1252 o al32utf8?

Comment: ¿Dónde veo eso? es mi primera vez con Oracle.